# Don't completely understand Source.delay method or there is error in akka-stream docs

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am reading akka-stream documentation about [KillSwitch](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html) and they have an example to illustrate the `KillSwitch.shutdown` method:

```
val countingSrc = Source(Stream.from(1)).delay(1.second, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
val lastSnk = Sink.last[Int]

val (killSwitch, last) = countingSrc
  .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(lastSnk)(Keep.both)
  .run()

doSomethingElse()

killSwitch.shutdown()

Await.result(last, 1.second) shouldBe 2
```

I have problems with understanding why expected result should be 2.
As I see this example, stream is put to 1 second delay. While it is paused the `shutdown()` gets invoked so the kill switch tells the stream to shutdown before the delay is completed. I don't see why first 2 elements of the stream are expected to be emitted and delivered to the sink.

Could you help and explain?

Note: if I run this example I get as I expected following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: last of empty stream
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$.$anonfun$last$3(Sink.scala:181)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding of the sample code. The result purely depends on the runtime duration of `doSomethingElse`. Only if it takes too less time you get the exception. To test this you can replace it with `Thread.sleep(2000)` and you will get a result back from the `Sink`. In case you increase the sleep value the result also increases.

Regarding your question in the comment:

`delay` shifts elements emission in time by a specified amount. Delay precision is 10ms to avoid unnecessary timer scheduling cycles. That is the reason you see this behaviour (you can check those details in the Scala docs of `Flow`).

In case you want to send one message per second, try `throttle` instead:

```
.throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. One more question to clarify: `Source.delay` specifies not one-time initial delay, but continuous delay, correct? Asking because when I remove the killswitch and then replace sink to be `Sink.foreach(println)` then I see elements printed in 1 second interval but in chunks of 2 elements.

Comment: Why elements are emitting in pairs is still not clear for me. I have tried to set buffer to 0 size but that does not make any difference with the backpressure overflow strategy. If I set buffer size to 10 then elements still are emitting in pairs, not in larger chunks.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar if you want to have 1 message per second there is a better approach. added it to my answer.

Comment: Sebastian, I want to understand the `delay`. I can read documentation and I did before posting the question. It says buffer matters here. But I don't see difference if I set buffer size 1 or 2 or 10. I expected if buffer size is 1 then it hold emitting (backpressures) until one element is in buffer AND delay timeout passed. But I still see elements printed two at a time. Also when I set buffer size to 10 I thought it would fill the buffer with 10 elements then wait till delay expires and then emit everything from the buffer. But it is doing something different, elements are printed in pairs.

Comment: In the initial example, as you pointed already, depending on the length of execution of `doSomethingElse()` the result will either be 2 or 4 or 6. But not 1 or 3 or 5, etc. I have reread doc and it says `Emits when there is a pending element in the buffer` so my expectation that elements will be printed in chunks of the buffer size is not correct. But I still don't get why they come in chunks of 2.

Comment: I think I got it. Since I have a simplest example here, where my `FlowOps` is the `Source` I don't have anything upstream. Will experiment with more elaborate flows and I think then I will be able to see buffers in action.